# How to deal with nested comments in FsLex

Tags: f#, fslex

There are single and multi-line comments available, like in C.

How to describe the rules for the lexer to ignore all the comments, even nested, such as these:

```
// comment /* nested comment /* and nested again? */ */
```

or like these:

```
/* comment // one more comment /* and more... */ */
```

**UPD:**

Here is the valid code to parse nested comments(thanks [Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/312325/sam)):

```
rule token = parse
  | "/*"        { comments 0 lexbuf }
  | [' ' '\t' '\n'] { token lexbuf }
  | eof         { raise End_of_file }

and comments level = parse
  | "*/"    {
          if level = 0 then token lexbuf
          else comments (level-1) lexbuf
        }
  | "/*"    { comments (level+1) lexbuf }
  | _       { comments level lexbuf }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was playing around with FsLex I found the [Ocamllex Tutorial](http://plus.kaist.ac.kr/~shoh/ocaml/ocamllex-ocamlyacc/ocamllex-tutorial/ocamllex-tutorial.html) a great help, in particular the [nested comments](http://plus.kaist.ac.kr/~shoh/ocaml/ocamllex-ocamlyacc/ocamllex-tutorial/sec-nested-comments.html) section was easy to change into F#.

Comment: Thank you, I suppose that it's what I need.
I'll try and share the result.